# Stereo Vision Real Distance Calculation

Tags: python, deep-learning, computer-vision, stereoscopy

I am new on stereo vision. I am trying to calculate real distance from stereo's disparity map and depth map. But I don't understand how can I do that. I have two output, one of them detect cars and giving x,y,w,h coordinates. The second one is that the stereo output with applied colormap.[image: det_stereo_img]

What I am trying to find car's distance from disparity map or depth map like this picture,
[image: ss_img]

I have an array of depth_map which is 480x640,
[image]

How can I find car's distance like above picture from depth map? Is there any formula for that or sample example?
Thank you.

Comment: given disparity map *and camera baseline*, depth map can be calculated. given depth map and a region, you can simply calculate the min() in that region... what _exactly_ is the issue? depth map values are linearly proportional to physical distances (i.e. mm, inches, whatever).

Comment: Hi @ChristophRackwitz, thank you for your comment. My purpose is that trying find car's distance and I want print them on the image like their labels. I am using pretrained deep learning model for calculate disparity map and depth map. if I take range of car's coordinate on depth map (numpy array) and calculate min() in that region, do I take the depth?

Comment: so... depth/disparity from **monocular vision**? oh boy, you better hope the network has learned to estimate object sizes well because that's the whole basis for estimating distance. -- the map gained from monocular depth _should_ be depth, not disparity. disparity only makes sense in stereo setups. -- if you could provide data (uint16/float TIFFs), I could take a look. -- basically yes, that's what I said. the depth map contains distances.

Comment: It's a stereo vision, @ChristophRackwitz I have left and right images with calibrated camera. The model which is I am using is here [CREStereo](https://github.com/ibaiGorordo/ONNX-CREStereo-Depth-Estimation)

Answer (score 0):

How someone has already said in the comments, you need the parameters of both cameras. In other words, the calibration information of your system:

- Intrinsics parameters of each camera (including lens distortion params)
- Extrinsics parameters i.e. where is one camera with respect to the other one in terms of a rotation matrix and a translation vector.

After that, yes, there is a *formula*. Please refer to my other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71973053/converting-a-disparity-map-to-a-depth-map-using-given-calibration-file/71991539#71991539).

If you want an example to go from disparity map to 3D points, you can go [here](https://github.com/decadenza/SimpleStereo/blob/master/examples/011%20Build3DPointCloud.py#L58) and follow the trail in the code.